# Embedding Private Framework into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I am trying to use some external Framework in my iPhone app. I did the following:

1. copied the xxx.framework inside my project folder
2. dragged the xxx.framework folder to Frameworks folder in xcode
3. clicked add to target and set the path to relative to the project
4. passed -ObjC flag in other flags (required by the framework)

when compiling i get the error **"ld: framework not found xxx"**

what could I possibly missed?

I googled around to find an answer and no luck so far and I need to make it work urgently

any help will be much appreciated

Thanks Alot

Yas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppStore does not allow dynamic linking to 3rd-party frameworks, which the reason why all iPhone libraries are distributed as static libraries (.a).

Anyway, if you really need to link to a 3rd-party framework, make sure the path to that framework is in the "Framework search path" (check "Project info").

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I checked it and it is empty... but that because the framework itself is inside the project folder. when i check the target info the "Framework search path" was pointing to the project folder

Comment: @ynk: Try to add `@executable_path` (not tested).

Comment: @ynk: Did you set that the "framework" should be copied into the destination?

Comment: @KennyTM: do you mean in the framework build settings?... in the final package .app there is a copy of the framework. 
it could be an issue with the device build of the framework... when i followed the same steps for the simulator build of the framework everything was working normally.. i will try to contact the developer of the framework just to make sure

Comment: @KennyTM: it turns out that the developer send me a framework without a library.. problem solved thanks for your help